# iOS screen goes black after launch screen finishes

Tags: ios, xcode

App was running fun until I added a launch screen using the default LaunchScreen.storyboard in the project. I've checked initial view controllers, my info.plist and the project details and everything seems to point to where it needs to be. Can anyone suggest anything else I can try? The launch screen consists of nothing but the default view controller and a single, cantered image view.

Comment: Check what you set in app icon and launchimage

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-add the images to Assets.xcassets.

1 - Click on Assets.xcassets folder

2 - Click the + sign to Import from Project.

3 - Select all images

That`s it!